# Why is material preview is freezing?

Tags: materials, performance

I've tried to make stone material following that [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YKRK82JeBo8). But after the middle part of the video, the blender starts to slow down in material preview mode. I know that some nodes are very "heavy" for performance but it's the first time I see a slow motion in material preview.

Here's my parameters of nodes:
[image]
Can you help me understand where the problem is?

Comment: Probably the three *Bump* nodes

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos yes, you're right. Can I replace them with something more suitable?

Comment: If you want to mix textures you should probably use a *Color Mix* node

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos thank you very much. It's enough for me. Will you post it as answer?